# Facebook Extra permission request button not found

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-permissions

[Hello I found this from developers.facebook.com permissions video.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crVTD.png)

[This one is from my developer account.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNRrc.png)

- As given in the above image there is a request button at the right side for request extra permissions while in my developer's account I didn't recognize that button.

Please guide developers and help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are used Facebook account via shared(someone how have share you access) 
You must have admin rights for request an extra permissions.

Comment: Thank you, @Umesh for your quick support, You are right I have developer rights for a facebook developer account. you save my day buddy.